# Tracking visits from LinkedIn

Tags: php, wordpress

I use LinkedIn and other Social Media to promote certain blog content on my Website. My website is on Wordpress and I therefore wrote a Plugin that created a widget for displaying the visit source. Once I have this source, I can store this on a table and can view the number of visits from each Social Media channel to test the effectiveness of the post.

The problem is that while I can identify click throughs from Facebook, Twitter, G+ etc. with no problem, I do not get any referer information from LinkedIn.

I use the read the information as follows:

```
//Get the referer from Wordpress
    $ref_raw = wp_get_raw_referer();
    echo '<li>RAW: '.( strlen($ref_raw)? $ref_raw: 'None' ).'</li>';

//Get the IP from the server to check
    $ref_srv = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    echo '<li>PHP: '.( strlen($ref_srv)? $ref_srv: 'None' ).'</li>';

//Get other information
    $ip = strlen($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"])? $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo '<li>REFERRER IP: '.( strlen($ip)? $ip: 'None' ).'</li>';
    $agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])&& strlen($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']: '';
    echo '<li>USER AGENT: '.( strlen($agent)? $agent: 'None' ).'</li>';
    echo '<li>URI: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'</li>';
```

The output from this code when a visit originated from Facebook is as follows:

- RAW: https://www.facebook.com/ PHP: https://www.facebook.com/
- REFERRER IP: 89.127.12.32
- USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 REFERRAL
- URI: /how-speed-affects-your-website/?fbclid=I123C-as

However, a visit from LinkedIn looks like this:

- RAW: None
- PHP: None
- REFERRER IP: 89.127.12.32
- USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
- REFERRAL TYPE: external
- URI: /how-speed-affects-your-website/

Any ideas why there is no referer data being transferred from LinkedIn? or any thoughts on how I can observe visits from LinkedIn by any other means?

Answer (score 1):

Is your own site using HTTPS? And do those links the users follow use HTTPS URLs?

If not, you will simply not get a referrer from LinkedIn in modern browsers, due to `Referrer-Policy`.

> no-referrer-when-downgrade (default)
>   This is the user agent's default behavior if no policy is specified. The URL is sent as a referrer when the protocol security level stays the same (HTTP→HTTP, HTTPS→HTTPS), but isn't sent to a less secure destination (HTTPS→HTTP).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Directives:

LinkedIn doesn’t actively specify a Referrer-Policy as far as I can see, so this fallback value will be used automatically.

So if your site doesn’t support HTTPS, or the links go to the HTTP version first, the browser is *forbidden* from sending you this info.

---

> or any thoughts on how I can observe visits from LinkedIn by any other means?

Check if they append any specific, uniquely named tracking parameters to outgoing links, like Facebook does with the `?fbclid=I123C-as`. Then you could take the existence of that parameter as an indicator that the user most likely followed a link from LinkedIn to your site.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I had not thought along these lines. In this instance, the site that captures the information is https and the link from LinkedIn also https - but as a lnkd.in shortened URL (like lnkd.in/gAr2KNK) - so there must be an SSL breakdown somewhere else.

Thank you and if you have any other thoughts these will be much appreciated.

Comment: `lnkd.in/gAr2KNK` redirects to `https://www.linkedin.com/slink?code=gAr2KNK` first, and then from there to your site. So I guess it depends on whether `lnkd.in/gAr2KNK` was accessed via HTTP or HTTPS to begin with. Not sure whether you are in control of those initial links, and can add the `https://` there?